# Download file while in ssh mode?

Tags: command-line, ssh, terminal, download

I use to navigate my remote servers with ssh. Sometimes i would like to download a file to open in my computer.

But the only way i know how to do it is to open a new command line window and use scp from local to remote.

is there a way to do this directly from the ssh server?

like a command that know my current ip so can set up everything automatically?

(wonderful would also be to do the upload in such a way...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this while trying to answer your question for myself:

https://askubuntu.com/a/13586/137980

Just install zssh and use Ctrl-@ to go into file transfer mode.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do it - I used ssh & scp many years the way you just described. But, you may configure ssh & scp in such a way that they don't require password each time, which is very comfortable! For this, you need:

1. generate keys by ssh-keygen - they can be also passphrase (= password) protected
2. copy the keys to remote machine to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

And then, each time you start a session, you run ssh-agent and ssh-add. You just enter the password once. And then you can just run scp/ssh many times, from scripts, etc., without the need to enter the password each time!

I don't remember the exact way how to configure all this, but have a look at manpages of all those useful tools! Many things can be automatized by placing them into ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc files.